# Writing for-each loop inside HAML and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I have a HAML like this:

```
- @my_patients_list.each do |patient|
  %tr
    %td= patient.name
    %td= patient.date_of_birth
    %td= patient.gender
    %td= patient.brand_name.name
    %td= patient.generics[0].name
```

notice the line  `%td= patient.generics[0].name`
I am cheating and only printing the first generic. But each patinet can have more than one generic. 
So it is a matter or another `for-each loop` for that part. But this HAML I just started using it and still not used to it.
Can someone help out with that extra loop I should write in HAML format so I can replace it with `patient.generics[0].name ?`
Probably let's just separate their generics names with a comma.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming generics is a string array and you want to separate by new td...

```
- @my_patients_list.each do |patient|
  %tr
    %td= patient.name
    %td= patient.date_of_birth
    %td= patient.gender
    %td= patient.brand_name.name
    - patient.generics.each do |gen|
       %td= gen.name
```

Otherwise if you just want to separate by comma...

```
- @my_patients_list.each do |patient|
      %tr
        %td= patient.name
        %td= patient.date_of_birth
        %td= patient.gender
        %td= patient.brand_name.name
        %td= patient.generics.map(&:name).join(',')
```

Comment: This will create table rows with varying numbers of `td` elements, which is likely not be what you want.

Comment: yes, he changed the question after i answered.  I edited to reflect the new question.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to seperate the generics name by comma, you may try this:

```
- @my_patients_list.each do |patient|
  %tr
    %td= patient.name
    %td= patient.date_of_birth
    %td= patient.gender
    %td= patient.brand_name.name
    %td= patient.generics.map(&:name).join(',')
```

It will print all associated generic names seperated by comma.